# Intersection of Schubert cycles

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

I want to compute intersection of the Schubert cell $\sigma_{(3,0)}$ with all the cells $\sigma_{a_1, a_2}$ in the grassmanian $G(2,5)$. I am not sure I am doing correctly but I can't see my mistake.  The notations are from the book *3264 and all that* by Eisenbud and Harris.

By definition $\sigma_{3,0}$ is the set of 2-planes spanned by the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\ 0 & * & * &* & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Let's intersect it with for example $\sigma_{1,1}$ which is the set of $2$-planes on the form $\begin{pmatrix} * & * & 1& 0& 0\\ * & * & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

For obtaining a transverse intersection I take the opposite flag $F_i' = \mathbb C\{e_n, e_{n-1}, \dots, e_{n-i}\}$. In this expression $\sigma_{1,1}'$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & * & *\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & * & * \end{pmatrix}$.

But a $2$-plane in $\sigma_{1,1}'$ will never contains $e_1$, i.e $\sigma_{3,0} \cap \sigma_{1,1}' = \emptyset$. This is surely not correct since $\text{codim} (\sigma_{3,0}) + \text{codim} (\sigma_{1,1}) = 5 < 6$. Can someone explain to me where is my mistake ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is when you say: "By definition $\sigma_{3,0}$ is the set of 2-planes spanned by the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\ 0 & * & * &* & 1 \end{pmatrix}$".

This is not true! The spaces spanned by those matrices represent only the main cell, in fact the Schubert variety is the union of the cells $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\ 0 & * & * &* & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\ 0 & * & * &1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\ 0 & * & 1 &0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The same applies for the other variety, thus as you can see $\langle e_1, e_4 \rangle$ is a point in both of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I just need to read a bit more for be sure I understood. I don't know yet Littlewood-Richardson rule, and the purpose of the exercise was probably to do the computations by hand. So I don't really understand the last line but I guess now I need to think a bit more about it.

Comment: Schubert Calculus is a way to compute products in the cohomology ring of the Grassmanian. These products can be translated into informations of the intersection of certain Schubert varieties if you use flags in general position (such as opposite flags). By the way the most important part here is that it's like you tried to intersect the varieties in the affine part and you didn't find any point, but you can think as they actually intersect at infinity because we are working in a projective space. A Schubert variety is a union of disjoint affine cells of decreasing dimension.

Comment: You intersected the bigger cells but you forgot to check for the small ones which do belong to the Schubert varieties.

Comment: You can think as if you try to find the intersection of two spheres which meet at a point. You think the two spheres as union of the intersection point and a  a cell of dimension 2. You check the intersection between the two cells and you don't find any point! But they actually intersect in the $0$-cells.

Comment: Ok I understand. But here could you explain to me why $e_1 \oplus e_4 \in \sigma_{1,1}' ?$ The closure should be remplacing some $1$ by $0$ but I will never got any positive coefficient in $e_1$ right ? Or am I mistaken again ?

Comment: It makes no sense to intersect two cycles, ie two elements in a ring. It makes sense to intersect varieties. In order to get a Schubert variety you need to chose a partition $\lambda$ AND a complete flag. If you change the flag you change the variety, even if the representing Schubert cycle stays the same. So if you change one of the two varieties they will probably have different points of intersection, no surprise.

Comment: Ok I understand. A last question : is it always true that two different Schubert cells intersect transversally ?

Comment: No. Every Schubert variety contains smaller Schubert varieties as you can see looking at the matrices. If you don't chose different flags, 2 Schubert varieties meet in a smaller Schubert variety or don't meet at all. If you chose two flags in general position, 2 Schubert varieties with that flags meet transversally. If you pick a flag, almost every flag is in general position with that flag, because this is an open condition in the variety of the complete flags variety $Fl(n)$. I still don't get why our two  varieties should meet but actually don't meet.

Comment: Ok thanks, I still I have recieved enough for think about it. Thanks again for the help !

Comment: Ok I got it! Even tho $s_{\lambda} \cdot s_{\mu} = s_{\nu}$  as polynomials in 2 or more (up to infinite) variables, we have $\sigma_{\lambda}\cdot \sigma_{\mu} = \sigma_{\nu} = 0$ because $\sigma_{\nu} = 0$ because $(4,1)$ is not possible for a Schubert variety and thus $\sigma_{\nu}$ is set to $0$ by default. We can say in this way: when you chose the standard flag for both your varieties you get as usual that the two varieties meet in a smaller variety with the same flag. This is not a transversal meeting of course, so this implies nothing in the ring of cohomology.

Comment: On the other hand, when you chose two flags in general position as two opposite flags, the meeting is automatically transversal. As you noticed, the new two varieties now do not meet at all, that is in fact a tranversal meeting, and that actually agrees with the fact that $\sigma_{\lambda}\cdot \sigma_{\mu} = \sigma_{\nu} = 0$.

Comment: Perfect !!! Do you have an example with non-trivial intersection I can train myself with ?

Comment: This is not perfect!! $(3,0) \cdot (1,1)= (4,1) + (3,1,1)$ both of them are $0$ in the cohomology ring of Grassmanian, now it's correct! You could  try to intersect Schubert varieties associated to the partitions $(4,2)$ and $(1,0)$.